# Azure b2c - password reset policy, update profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

As part of my sign up process I validate additional data at point of registration that goes off to an Azure function with 2 bits of info before being able to register for the system.

The above all works as expected however I also have the requirement to re-check data if a change is made on the account and this includes a password reset.  I don't want to over complex the AD b2c password reset process and keep it largely vanilla.  Is it possible to modify the reset flow to set a flag on the users b2c profile when a password reset is performed.  That way when they get back on to my site before granting full access I can check whether the flag is set perform the extra re-validation away from b2c?

Or is there a way of extending the reset page to accept the pieces of information using the same process I have for sign up as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add more orchestration steps to the PasswordReset UserJourney to write the attribute flag using the AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId TP.